# HDMI output broken after Antergos install

Tags: display, hdmi, antergos

After installing Antergos with KDE everything is working fine (as far as I can tell) except my HDMI monitor doesn't work. Instead of rendering anything properly it displays whatever the first image that appears on it is but broken into lines with black lines in between.

I have an NVidia GPU and I think it's Optimus (I got 2 lines following [this](https://antergos.com/wiki/hardware/bumblebee-for-nvidia-optimus/#Do_I_have_an_Optimus_card)) so I assumed the Nouveau drivers just weren't up to scratch and it was trying to render the HDMI with those. Installing the proprietary nvidia drivers with [nvidia-installer](https://antergos.com/wiki/hardware/graphics/antergos-nvidia-installer-2/) made the OS unbootable (GRUB loaded, selecting Antergos gave a black screen).

Installing Bumblebee (`-b` with `nvidia-installer`) had much the same effect. Attempting to revert to Nouveau (`-n` with `nvidia-installer`) fixed this however once I logged in KDE Plasma froze on load and I could get no further (particularly strange because that's exactly what I thought I had before when it worked).

It's possible that the drivers aren't the issue at all but at this point I have no clue how to make my HDMI screen work.

Laptop model: Gigabyte P57v7
CPU: Intel i7-7700HQ
GPU: NVidia Geforce GTX 1070

I'll add logs tomorrow because I'll have to boot into non-graphical to get them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future readers with a similar problem: the fix that worked for me is [here](https://forum.antergos.com/topic/10347/hdmi-output-broken-after-install/7).

> The solution [here](https://github.com/Bumblebee-Project/Bumblebee/issues/764#issuecomment-234494238) of adding `acpi_osi=! acpi_osi="Windows 2009"` to the kernel parameters both allowed the reinstalled nouveau drivers to finish booting and the nvidia drivers to work at all.